# Shortcut within a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm a total noob an only started learning JS several days ago. I'm somewhat familiar with html and css though. I created this code as an exercise. It tells wheter the number put in the form is positive, negative or 0. I also wanted it to list all the numbers used. However, I don't want the app to list the result  (e.g. "Positive number") if someone mistakenly hits "Check" before typing in another number. My only solution was to add the document.create.element part after each condition. But I feel that there should be a simpler way, is it possible to wite it just once and then just invoke a kind of shortcut for it in the two remaining conditional statements?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>What number is it?</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="numer" id="number">
    <button onclick="calculate()" id="przycisk">Check</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>
        function calculate() {
            var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
            if (num > 0) {
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode(num);
                para.appendChild(node);
                var element = document.getElementById("div1");
                element.appendChild(para);
                number.value = "Positive number";
            }
            if (num == 0) {
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode(num);
                para.appendChild(node);
                var element = document.getElementById("div1");
                element.appendChild(para);
                number.value = 0;
            }
            if (num < 0) {
                var para = d ocument.createElement("p");
                var node = d ocument.createTextNode(num);
                para.appendChild(node);
                var element = d ocument.getElementById("div1");
                element.appendChild(para);
                number.value = "Negative number";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want the result to be in the input box? It's just not very intuitive to have to erase the result each time you want to input a new number.. If you need to do that though, I would recommend just making the result a placeholder instead. This way the text will disappear when the user wants to enter a new number. Take a look here for more info on placeholder..https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: Yeah the only reason I wanted it in the input box was that it posed a challenge and I wanted to see if I could figure out how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never rely on Javascript's implicit type conversion rules. If you want to compare a variable to a number, make sure that this variable is a valid number in the first place.

Here's a corrected copy of your code (although I agree with the commenter that displaying the result in the input box is quite unconventional).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>What number is it?</title>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="numer" id="number">
<button onclick="calculate()" id="przycisk">Check</button> 
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>

function calculate() {
    var num = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);

    if (Number.isNaN(num)) {
        // not a number, do nothing
        return;
    }

    var message = "0";

    if (num < 0)
        message = "Negative number";
    else if (num > 0)
        message = "Positive number";

    number.value = message;

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(num));
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(para);
}
 

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

This way, the flow is more logical and there's no need to repeat any code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like below. I just removed all duplicate code, call it only once if enter value by user is number and remove `if/else` as well.(like below)

```js
function calculate() {
  var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
  if(!isNaN(num)){
    number.value = (num > 0) ? "Positive number" 
                  :(num < 0) ? "Negative number"
                  : "0";
    
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(num);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>What number is it?</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="numer" id="number">
    <button onclick="calculate()" id="przycisk">Check</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that `add` is called in all three branches, so it can be factored out.

Comment: @georg no it is not as if value is other than number we don't want add that in list.

Comment: well, that's weird. You might want to fix this.

Comment: @georg now I even remove if/else also and used ternary which also reduces redundant code. :)